# write all months first three letters with numeric data

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to write all 12 months (first three letters) something like this:

```
for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
    echo "<div class='cpitem' data-x='???'>" . date('M') . "</div>\n";
}
```

The final result should be:

```
<div class='cpitem' data-x='01'>JAN</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='02'>FEB</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='03'>MAR</div>
...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and use `$x` as month. Then, could use this timestamp with [`date()`](http://php.net/date). The format of `date()` are :

- `m` *"Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros"*
- `M` *"A short textual representation of a month, three letters"*

```
for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
    $tm = strtotime("2000-$x-01"); // Here, 2000 is arbitrary.
    echo "<div class='cpitem' data-x='".date('m',$tm)."'>" . strtoupper(date('M',$tm)) . "</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div class='cpitem' data-x='01'>JAN</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='02'>FEB</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='03'>MAR</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='04'>APR</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='05'>MAY</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='06'>JUN</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='07'>JUL</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='08'>AUG</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='09'>SEP</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='10'>OCT</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='11'>NOV</div>
<div class='cpitem' data-x='12'>DEC</div>
```

Comment: could you find who downvoted your answer and my question? I think it's a user who deleted his wrong answer, posted just after you.